# Calculating Z-axis Torque on a 3-D Printer

Tags: torque, 3d-printing, stepper-motor

I recently built a large CoreXY 3D printer and I am wondering if my 4 z-axis stepper motors combined will have enough torque to accelerate the build plate with a heavy 3d print. During the building to designing process, I noticed the majority of people who build 3d printers, such as myself, do not calculate the required torque needed to accelerate the print bed. Most people just look at existing designs to see what has worked or fail and slow the acceleration in the firmware to a minimum.

I think it would be useful to the 3d printing community if someone could demonstrate methods to calculate the required torque for the CoreXY printer below? The following information may be of use.

- Build plate:
  635mmx610mm and 6.35mm thickness Mic6 aluminum, mass 6.64kg. Mass of frame
  for build plate is ~1kg. Total load on z-axis ~7.35kg.
- The 4 z-axis steppers on the bottom make a rectangle that is 543.64mmx789.9mm.
- Z-axis spans about 625mm.
- Z-axis acceleration: 0.5 m/s2
- Z-axis top speed: 10mm/s

Motor torque specs can be found in the pictures below.

[image: stepper]
[image: side-view]
[image: angle view]

Edit adding dimensions of all rotating bodies.  Units are in mm.
[image: rotating bodies]
[image: lead screw dimensions]

Comment: To calculate torques one needs to generally know the reduced inertia of the system, so to do a good job we also need to know the size and shape of all rotating masses including the ballscrews.

Comment: So, did you do a test since you have built it? Often how engineers work...

Comment: interesting design... my first guess, without full detail, would be that much of the load on the motors will come from friction of the mechanism due to overconstraint. Suggest looking up questions here about how to convert load on power screws to torque. Then compare to torque-vs-rpm (vs voltage or current limit) curves from stepper motor mfg. Note the stepper motor driver circuitry may not produce the max rated torque, as there may be tradeoffs for smooth motion, power consumption, cost, and EMI.

Comment: @SolarMike the printer is built mechanically but I am in the process of wiring the steppers, heating elements to my duet3 motherboard.   Then I can test but this is probably a couple weeks out.

Comment: Well, start by using a spring balance to find the force needed to drag thee assembly - that gives you an idea of what the motor will need to do.

Comment: @joojaa I have added an edit that gives specific diameters of all rotating bodies.  Let me know if anything else is needed.

Comment: Lead of the screw a ts as a sort of gearing would be nice to know too.

Comment: @joojaa lead screw information added.